# Select first 12 value of command for

Tags: php

I have a command 'for'.

```
for ($i=0;$i<($term*$time);$i++){
```

is it possible to made the summary of only first 12 values of 'i' (for example `for $i=0 thru $i=11)`?

---

EDIT:

The complete code is:

```
for ($i=0;$i<($term*$time);$i++){
      $tmp = (($pay) - ($balance*($rate/100/$time)));
      $diff = round($tmp,2);
      $int  = round(($balance*$rate/100/$time),2);
      $princ = $balance - $diff;
      $balance = round($balance,0);       $m = $i + 1;
      echo "<tr><td>$m. mese</td><td> &euro;".
         number_format($balance, 2, ',', '.')."</td><td> &euro;".
         number_format($int, 2, ',', '.')."</td><td> &euro;".
         number_format($pay, 2, ',', '.')."</td></tr>";
```

It show the amortization of a loan or mortgage.
'i' are the months and this code show on each row the payment and balance. I'd like to add an additional row each 12 months that calculate the summary of values contained in the 12 previous row.

Is it possible?

Comment: Add a `break` when `i` reaches `12` ?

Comment: You mean `for ($i=0;($i<($term*$time)) && ($i<12);$i++){` ?

Comment: See my edit. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249478/select-first-12-value-of-command-for)

Comment: if you want to do something every twelve months then in your loop just add some code to check whether $i is divisible by 12 without a remainder (using a [modulo operation](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-modulo-operator-in-php--cms-32393). If it is, then you can write your summary. Of course you might also need another variable to which you add the data from the previous 12 rows, so you can sum them. And then you'd clear it after processing the 12th one (assuming you can ever have more than 12 rows).

Comment: @ADyson please can you give me an example? I'm not an expert of php and progamming

Comment: No, sure, but we all learn the most by doing. My suggestion involves several steps. Have you tried any of them? Are you stuck on a particular one?

Comment: @ADyson I'm almost sure that I can check if $i is divisible by 12 without a remainder... But after that, how I can bring the values of previous row?

Comment: you don't bring them during the 12th execution, you add them beforehand in another variable (perhaps an array, which you created outside the loop, and then added to during the looping process), and then just use them at that time. Or, if it's just a simple running total you want, then just create a $sum variable (outside the loop), and increase its value every time you loop. It depends...you didn't say exactly what extra info should be displayed on the 12th time, or where it comes from. I know it's a summary of some values, but not which ones, or how they're "summarised"

Comment: @ADyson first of all, thanks a lot for your support. This script is a simulation of the scheduled payment of a loan or mortgage. It show all payments for each months, and each months has different payment.. A user insert in inpunt the total value of loan, tax and years and the script simulate the amortization. What I'd like to have is that if the loan is for 3 years, after each years (then after each 12 row/months) will be showed the total of payment of that year.

Comment: @ADyson can you help me? In which way I can temporary store the values of $balance, $int and $pay for each $i outside of original loop?

Comment: Well if you just want a total at the end, you can just keep adding to them every time you run the loop. e.g. `$totalBalance = 0; for ($i=0;$i<($term*$time);$i++){ .... $balance = round($balance,0);       $m = $i + 1; if ($i % 12 == 0) { //display the 12-month total } else { $totalBalance += $balance; } ...`  something like that, for example. And same for the others.

Comment: @ADyson thanks a lot for your support. Despite I was not able to get the totalBalance, thanks to your code I get what I wanted after 12 months doing other calculations... Thanks a lot!